# How do I refer from another table for SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Situation is this:
I have a table for staff and another one for course.
In course I will have a column called coordinator which will refer to the staff_id.
This is because some staff are coordinators and some are not, etc etc.

Staff_id is an IDENTITY hence it is auto-incrementing and I have to make sure the in the course table, it won't follow this auto-increment.

I'm just unsure how do I implement the check constraint for this case.

Comment: Sounds like a foreign key constraint. Google foreign key constraints or referential integrity, should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements properly you can add a foreign key constraint to the table so that it references itself:

```
ALTER TABLE Staff 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Staff_Coordinator FOREIGN KEY (Coordinator)
REFERENCES Staff (StaffID)
```

**ADENDUM**

I think I had misunderstood your requirements, I missed the part about a course table. So now I am thinking that the course table needs to link back to the staff table, in which case the command would be:

```
ALTER TABLE Course
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Course_Coordinator FOREIGN KEY (Coordinator)
REFERENCES Staff (StaffID)
```

You are of course free to implement your own naming convention for constraints.

Answer (score 2):

> I have to make sure the in the course table, it won't follow this auto-increment.

Do you just mean that you don't want the `coordinator` field in the course table to auto-increment? It won't unless you tell it to.

For example these two tables would work fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff
(
    `staff_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE Courses
(
    `course_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `coordinator_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `coursename` VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`),
    INDEX `coordid` (`coordinator_id`)
)
```

Of course, as GarethD says, you can then additionally add constraints to guarantee that the coordinator_id is correctly filled in and the corresponding record exists in staff.